# Ejs include partials files not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, partials

I am trying to use ejs in a node js project.
I have managed to render the views file(.ejs') and use the .js data in it.
and getting the desired webpage including the stylesheet.
the problem occurs only while using partial
After importing the header.ejs file in customer.ejs I am getting the exact text syntax of the header.ejs on the webpage.
 `<%- include("partials/header") %>`
In short customer.ejs is locating the header file and importing the it fine. but not rendering it

> Output

```
�� <�head> <�link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"> <�title>Customer<�/title> <�/head> 
Name: abc
```

my directories are as follows
`project\public\css\style.scc`
`project\views\partials\header.ejs>`
`project\views\customer.ejs`
`project\app.js`
i am using Express
my syntax are as follows

> app.js

```
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.set('views', './views');
 app.set('view engine', "views");
```

> customer.ejs

```
<html >
<%- include("partials/header") %> 
<body>
    <h1>
         Name: <%= customer.name %>
    </h1>   
    
 </body>
 </html>
```

> header.ejs

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    
    <title>Customer</title>
</head>
```

> Things i tried

`<%- include partials/header %>`
`<%- include("partials/header") %>`
`<%- include("./partials/header") %>`
`<%- include("partials/header.ejs") %>` and several more..
also tried using the `express-partial` module.
also tried it on different browsers.
Please let me know if i am doing something wrong or using a decrypted method
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: it should be `app.set('view engine', "ejs");` not sure what `<�` is, perhaps your editor, system settings or how you copy things around

Comment: Exactly Lawrence, He needs to set the view engine to ejs

Comment: tried that too.. still no change. And If that was the problem I would have not get the `Name: abc` either.  the <? symbol you see in the out put is exactly as it is on the browser's web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question after surfing google for a significant amount of time.
Something went wrong with the Unicode
After pasting the following in the root dir the problem was solved. Just after hitting enter, my entire app.js got changed to some Chinese text. but ctrl+z brought my code back.

```
Get-Content .\app.js -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 
.\app-fixed.js ; Move-Item -Path .\app-fixed.js -Destination .\app.js - 
Confirm -Force
```